# Visa availability is longer than the availability of the passport

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa

What happens if the visa availability is longer than the availability of the passport?

In my case, a Romanian with a Romanian passport (5 years availability) who wants to get a tourist visa for United States which usually is for 10 years. A fact that might be important, Romania is not in the [Visa Waiver Program.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program)

Will the visa be considered expired when my passport will expire or it could be used later too (with a new passport, of course).